# Stop unwanted WP redirection to new url

Tags: redirect, urls, wp-redirect

I had a custom type post, for which I changed the url.
I have refreshed permalinks and cleared site and browser cache.
The old url now redirects to the new url automatically. Possibly because the post ID is the same (?). 
Is it possible the stop the old url to direct to the new url?

Comment: wordpress database migrate query apply ?

Comment: Have you refresh permalinks in admin ?

Comment: I have refreshed permalinks and cleared site and browser cache.

Comment: search-replace plugin used and replace old url to new url https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WordPress uses a function called `wp_old_slug_redirect()` to find out if you're looking for a post whose slug was recently changed and redirect you to its new home.

If you want to prevent this behaviour for this specific post, delete the `_wp_old_slug` post meta entry from the database for that post.

If you want to prevent this behaviour for *all* posts, prevent the function from being used at all:

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_old_slug_redirect' );
```

Comment: It worked - thanks. I went directly to the database with phpmyadmin, but here's another way to do it:https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238514/can-i-safely-delete-a-record-manually-in-the-wp-postmeta-table

Comment: We had a an auto updating woocommerce product with two very similar names and slugs and somehow wordpress added _wp_old_slug to create a redirect loop. 'Fantastic'.