# Documentation for post meta

Tags: meta-query, post-meta

Trying to solve [this problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/292488/stop-unwanted-wp-redirection-to-new-url) I tried to find the complete list of all available/possible default "post meta" tags/entries. I couldn't find this info documented anywhere. Any pointers?

Comment: Given that plugins and themes can add meta, it's impossible to list all possibilities. If you have access to the database you could get a list of _currently use_ meta keys with a simple SQL query.

Comment: I'm obviously referring to the default post-meta. Not those added by plugins and themes. I know how to find currently used post-meta. I never though that a question asking for documentation would invoke a negative vote.

Comment: There are lots of those and it would take sone time to document them all. Are you interested in all post meta keys or just the „public“ ones (no leading underscore)?

Comment: to get all meta of a post, try this function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom

Answer (score 1):

There is no official documented list of all possible post meta keys in core. The closest I could for anything unofficial was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315125/reserved-keys-for-user-meta-in-wordpress-about-me) answer on Stack Exchange:

> You probably don't want to use the following *post meta* keys:
>
> - `_thumbnail_id` - Used to store the featured image ID
> - `_edit_last`    - Used by the *Heartbeat API*
> - `_edit_lock`  - Used by the *Heartbeat API*
> - `_wp_page_template` - Stores the page template.
> - `_wp_attached_file`
> - `_wp_attachment_metadata`
> - `_menu_item_{url, object, object_id, target, classes, xfn, ... }`
>
> as your custom meta keys, as they might be overwritten by the
>   WordPress Core.

However this is over 3 years old and not comprehensive. It's only based on the answering user checking for all the keys in their database. You'll notice that `_wp_old_slug` is missing, for example.